# Any alternative for '<Modelname>.find()' function in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

> MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback

I am getting this error message when I am trying to run a callback function in the .find() method of mongoose. Please suggest any alternative way to perform the operation done by.find() method.

Comment: I think it's better to use async/await functions instead of callbacks

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58190831/10574970

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76332845/6463558