# MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to get all users from the database but it shows **Model.find() no longer accepts a callback.** I am not able to figure out how I can get the data from mongodb database.

````
router.get('/users',(req,res) => {
    User.find({},(err,data) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send(data)
    })
})```
````

Comment: Please remove `mongoose-web-server` tag from this question

Answer (score 2):

Here we use async await to solve this issue
Also don't promisify it

---

`const data = await Model.find()`

---

```
router.get('/allUsers', async (req, res) => {
  const allUsers = await User.find()
  res.status(200).send({
    status: 'Success',
    data: allUsers,
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can use instead of a callback:

```
router.get('/users',(req,res) => {
  User.find({}).then(
    data => res.send(data)
  ).catch(
    err => throw err
  );
});
```

or with Async/await:

```
router.get('/users', async (req,res) => {
  try {
    const data = await User.find({});
    res.send(data);
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#dropped-callback-support):

`Model.find` method no longer accepts callback. It always returns a promise. You can use the `async/await` or `.then()/.catch()` method to handle the promise like:

```js
try {
  cont res = await User.find({})
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

You can find the method list in the above link. Let's also take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/7.2.1/lib/model.js#LL2058C1-L2069C3) of `Model.find()` method:

```
Model.find = function find(conditions, projection, options) {
  _checkContext(this, 'find');
  if (typeof arguments[0] === 'function' || typeof arguments[1] === 'function' || typeof arguments[2] === 'function' || typeof arguments[3] === 'function') {
    throw new MongooseError('Model.find() no longer accepts a callback');
  }

  const mq = new this.Query({}, {}, this, this.$__collection);
  mq.select(projection);
  mq.setOptions(options);

  return mq.find(conditions);
};
```

The method will verify the arguments and throw that error if a callback argument is passed in.