# mongoose error: model.find() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, node-modules, mongoose-populate

I am using latest version mongoose 7.3.1 and express latest version

```
C:\Users\rahul\blogers\Blog-with-Database-Step1-Answer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2072
    throw new MongooseError('Model.find() no longer accepts a callback');
    ^

MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback
    at Function.find (C:\Users\rahul\blogers\Blog-with-Database-Step1-Answer\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2072:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rahul\blogers\Blog-with-Database-Step1-Answer\app.js:114:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Node.js v20.2.0

please help me for this code

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76332845/6463558

Answer (score 0):

In new mongoose version. It should be used a specfic method to find data.

If you want to find one data, you can use `Model.findOne` method.

If you want to find more then one data, you can use `Model.findMany` method.

Use of the two methods is the same.

For reference, visit the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).