# Gettin error in mongoose "MongooseError: Model.findById() no longer accepts a callback "

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Here is my code:

```
module.exports.profile = function(req, res){
    if(req.cookies.user_id){
        User.findById(req.cookies.user_id, function(err, user){
            if(user){
                return res.render('user_profile', {
                    title: "User Profile",
                    user: user
                })
            }
            return res.redirect('/users/sign-in');
        });
    }else{
        return res.redirect('/user/sign-in');
    }
}
```

I am trying to authenticate a simple login page using mongoose

Comment: You can use "then, catch". e.g. User.findById(_id).then(user => { if(user){ return ...} }).catch(err =>{ return ...})

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76332845/6463558